# Create Shape For TextField in JavaFX With Css

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, javafx-3d

I need to create this shape for `TextField` using CSS

[image: Sample Pic]

But I only managed to create the following UI:

[image: My Pic]

How can I create text field like Sample Pic?

Comment: This is so beautiful ! https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-fx-shape` property of [`Region`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) to specify a [SVG path](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html).

```css
.login-box {
    -fx-spacing: -15;
    -fx-fill-height: false;
}

.login-box > .button {
    -fx-shape: "M0,1 L1,0 L2,1 L1,2 Z";
    -fx-min-width: 60;
    -fx-max-width: 60;
    -fx-min-height: 60;
    -fx-max-height: 60;
}

.login-box > .textfield-container {
    -fx-spacing: 8;
}

.login-box > .textfield-container > .text-field {
    -fx-shape: "M200,0 H0 V30 H170 Z";
}

.login-box > .textfield-container > .password-field {
    -fx-shape: "M170,0 H0 V30 H200 Z";
}

.login-box > .textfield-container > .text-field, .login-box > .textfield-container > .password-field {
    -fx-min-width: 200;
    -fx-max-width: 200;
    -fx-min-height: 30;
    -fx-max-height: 30;
    -fx-padding: 4 30 4 8;
}
```

Both the SVG-Paths start at the top-right corner (`M200,0`/`M170,0`) then drawing to the top-left corner (`H0`), continue drawing down to the bottom-left corner (`V30`) then drawing to the bottom-right corner (`V170`/`V200`) and finally closing the path (`Z`).

View structure:

```
login-box                                (HBox)
    |---- textfield-container            (VBox)
    |         |--- text-field            (TextField)
    |         |--- password-field        (PasswordField)
    |
    |---- button                         (Button)
```